# rvm : Failed to create the file bin-ruby-2.6.3.tar.bz2.part: Permission denied

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm trying to install unsuccessfully ruby from rvm

```
rvm install ruby
```

And I have this result

> Failed to create the file bin-ruby-2.6.3.tar.bz2.part: Permission
>   denied

Did you have an idea about this problem ?

Comment: I was having this problem while following the install instructions here: https://github.com/rvm/ubuntu_rvm but the issue was solved by doing a full reboot (I thought just refreshing the terminal would work but it didn't)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've successfully resolved the problem by running:

`sudo chown -R goms:rvm /usr/share/rvm/*`

Where `goms`is the current user.

Comment: `sudo chown -R CURRENT-USER:rvm /usr/share/rvm/*`

Can get the `CURRENT-USER` using `whoami`

Comment: you should rather add user to required `rvm` group instead of changing ownership of files

Answer (score 0):

From RVM installation manual:
https://github.com/rvm/ubuntu_rvm
"all sudoers are automatic added to rvm group at install" - please make sure that you are in rvm group. You can verify this using `groups` command.

If you're not, you can add your user to required group with this command:
`sudo usermod -aG rvm $USER`
Then you have to reboot your system.

Answer (score 0):

So, I had exactly the same problem as you, i followed a tutorial page and had already attached my user to the `rvm` group.

And **as indicated in the tutorial: re-login**, but it didn't worked, the `rvm install x.x.x` wasn't working as expected .

So when i came here, instead of doing `sudo chown -R username:rvm /usr/share/rvm/*` as proposed by Goms, i just hit the reboot and it solved my problem.

I had to **reboot** the system so the permissions changes could take effect.

maybe it helps someone too

fedora 35 here

Comment: newbie issues, i know :)